# How to import sql files which are more than 10mb in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I can't import a sql file that is more than 10 MB.

Is there any way to import a file that's more than 10MB using **MYSQL**?

EDIT:

I have a mysql dump file which is more than 10MB. I can't import it in my localhost. When i try, the following error occurs:

```
ERROR:
You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, I routinely import gigabytes of data without problem.

Comment: Removed my answer - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011253/import-large-file-on-mysql-db which seems to encounter the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `mysql` command line tool? Not all programs that have *my* in their name are the same program.

Comment: No. I am not using the command line tool. I tried using phpmyadmin

Comment: I'm think that this error has to do with the `max_allowed_packet` size being too small (which is commonly set on 1MB max).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should to do it via the commandline.

Since you wrote localhost above, I assume you have access. It also has no time limit for importing data.

```
mysql -u username -p database < location/to/your/dump.sql
```

`-p` will ask you for your password. If the user has no password, ignore the flag

---

edit: @Marco Mariani: This is a possibility, but keep in mind that this limit will be used for *ALL* of your PHP applications on the same server. You could change it back after the import but that's rather tedious and a high upload limit isn't a good idea IMO.

Answer (score 8):

copy and pasted below from: [Upper limit for Upload Limit and Post Limit in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988214/upper-limit-for-upload-limit-and-post-limit-in-php)
copy and pasted below from: http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/

It's how i overcome the exact same issue.

When trying to import large SQL files into mysql using phpmyadmin, the phpmyadmin documentation offers a few solutions, but I find the easiest method to overcome this is…

Find the config.inc.php file located in the phpmyadmin directory. In my case it is located here: ? 1
`C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\config.inc.php`

Find the line with `$cfg['UploadDir']` on it and update it to: ? 1
`$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';`

Create a directory called ‘upload’ within the phpmyadmin directory. ? 1 `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\upload\`

Then place the large sql file that you are trying to import into the new upload directory. Now when you go onto the db import page within phpmyadmin console you will notice a drop down present that wasn’t there before – it contains all of the sql files in the upload directory that you have just created. You can now select this and begin the import.

If you’re not using WAMP on Windows, then I’m sure you’ll be able to adapt this to your environment without too much trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much for these instructions, i was looking for over an hour on how to do this, but command line was not working at all, this totally worked.

Comment: THIS IS THE BEST SOLUTION SO FAR I COULD FOUND! WORKS LIKE A CHARM! THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 3):

**To resolve upload issues**
you need to edit the php.ini file

edit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

> change upload file size then you can upload the maximum size DB :
>
> **upload_max_filesize = 999M**
>
> to change post data limit :
> **post_max_size = 99M**

then execute the command

> sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/) (obs: [SQLYog community edition download link](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list)) to import the data in mysql. There is no 10MB limit (from php.ini using phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `MySQL` in `Xampp` then do the steps below.
Find the following in `php.ini` file

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

And change their sizes according to your need. I'm using these values

```
post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 30M
max_execution_time = 4500
max_input_time = 4500
memory_limit = 850M
```

**Note:1** `upload_max_filesize` is essential **But** it's better to change all.

**Note:2** You must restart apache service.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using php/phpmyadmin.

You can change the max_upload setting in php.ini (or do it from the command line)

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to import a file that is more than 2 mb, try importing in zipped format. Make sure you name the zip as filename.sql.zip , in case of other compressions change the extension accordingly. I imported a 10 mb file (magento sample data), after compression it became 1.8 mb, and upload done.

Answer (score 0):

Try zipping the `.sql` file. Worked great for me.