# Upper limit for Upload Limit and Post Limit in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have changed my upload and post limit options to 8000 M. However, when I try to import a table from a text file that's only 12.4 MB I get an error saying:

```
You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.
```

Is 8000 M to big?

Comment: Have they been changed in `phpinfo();`

Comment: Yes, in phpinfo() it says 8000M

Comment: post_max_size 8000M 8000M and upload_max_filesize 8000M 8000M

Comment: What code generates this error message?  Is it trying to copy this file to mysql?

Comment: I import the data using phpmyadmin using the import option (load local)and I get this error message.

Comment: `post_max_size` can not be more than `memory_limit`

Comment: so do I just increase memory limit?

Comment: you need to do as it says, read the documentation, its a **phpmyadmin** issue. your php.ini changes will have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

> Be careful not to exceed the 32 bit signed integer limit (if you're using 32bit versions) as it will cause your script to fail.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to check these values in php.ini

max_execution_time

max_input_time

memory_limit

I would also lower your post_max_size and upload_max_size to a more reasonable level (like maybe 128 or 256M)

Also if you really need to get the data in, you could do it from the command line

```
mysql -u username -p database < dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

copy and pasted below from:   http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/

It's how i overcome the exact same issue.

> When trying to import large SQL files into mysql using phpmyadmin, the
>   phpmyadmin documentation offers a few solutions, but I find the
>   easiest method to overcome this is…
>
> Find the config.inc.php file located in the phpmyadmin directory. In
>   my case it is located here: ? 1
>   C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\config.inc.php
>
> Find the line with $cfg['UploadDir'] on it and update it to: ? 1
>   $cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';
>
> Create a directory called ‘upload’ within the phpmyadmin directory. ?
>   1      C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\upload\
>
> Then place the large sql file that you are trying to import into the
>   new upload directory. Now when you go onto the db import page within
>   phpmyadmin console you will notice a drop down present that wasn’t
>   there before – it contains all of the sql files in the upload
>   directory that you have just created. You can now select this and
>   begin the import.
>
> If you’re not using WAMP on Windows, then I’m sure you’ll be able to
>   adapt this to your environment without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you have exceeded the 3.2 GB limit (8,000 MB) imposed by a 32 bit process, with PHP.  As such, you likely can not use the full 8,000 MB as you have specified.  I have had PHP hang on code when processing close to 2000 MB as memory to use with a 32 bit PHP.