# php code to mysql database export

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practice: Import mySQL file in PHP; split queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883079/best-practice-import-mysql-file-in-php-split-queries)

How to import import *.sql file into database and export db to *.sql file in php coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec("mysqldump database -u username -p password  > output.sql");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html