# How to export and import mysql database with its data using php script?

Tags: php, mysql

I was asked to create an export and import mysql database with it's structure and data into a .sql file using php scripting and not phpmyadmin to make the user be able to backup his data?

Does anybody have an idea how to do that??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it have to be just PHP?  Could always use mysqldump, and if it needed to be a PHP script, could use mysqldump through exec.

Comment: Dup of [Easy way to export a SQL table without access to the server or phpMyADMIN](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81934/), [php code to mysql database export](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2491728/90527),  [Best practice: Import mySQL file in PHP; split queries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1883079/90527), and likely [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+MySQL+%2Bexport+%2Bimport).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

either

```
$tableName  = 'mypet';
$backupFile = 'backup/mypet.sql';
$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

or

```
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip >     $backupFile";
system($command);
```

Comment: anybody knows how to import it to phpmyadmin through a php script

Comment: Look at the tutorial. There is a `"LOAD DATA INFILE 'backupFile' INTO TABLE $tableName";`section.

Answer (score 16):

**SAFE and WORKING SOLUTION** :

```
EXPORT_TABLES("localhost","user","pass","db_name"); 
// has 5th and 6th optional parameters too.
```

Latest version is available at github: 
[**Export.php**](https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/my-sql-export%20(backup)%20database.php) + [**Import.php**](https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/my-sql-import%20(restore)%20database.php)

Comment: Thank you! this is a best code. because other codes work with "exec" or "system" functions.this functions disabled on Linux hosts. but this script worked on Linux hosts.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks for sharing this code Mr.tazo...It's working perfectly for me...Thanks.

Comment: fantastic and its very useful one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice class that worked just fine for me.
if it says fopen access denied, try to change the folder permissions.

https://github.com/clouddueling/mysqldump-php