# Import MySQL file in PHP

Tags: php, import

I have a MySQL file which I want to import via PHP 5.

In the name of user friendliness the user should not use tools like PHPmyadmin etc. Just hit a button and the file will get imported.

I have already created code to upload the file to a location on the server.

The file looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('', '0', '10', '', '1', 'be34112', '4536.jpg', '','','','0');
SET @master_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO products_description VALUES ('', '1', @master_id, '1', 'Kjole', '', 'beskrivelse', '2000', '25', 'kjole.xml', '', '', '');
INSERT INTO products_to_categories VALUES ('',@master_id,'5');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('', @master_id, '10', '12', '1', 'be34112', '4536.jpg', '200','','','0');
SET @variant_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO products_description VALUES ('', '1', @variant_id, '1', 'Kjole', '', 'beskrivelse', '2000', '25', 'kjole.xml', '', '', '');
INSERT INTO options_to_products VALUES ('', @variant_id, '1', '1');
INSERT INTO options_to_products VALUES ('', @variant_id, '', '2');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('', @master_id, '20', '17', '1', 'be34113', '4537.jpg', '200','','','0');
SET @variant_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO products_description VALUES ('', '1', @variant_id, '1', 'Kjole', '', 'beskrivelse æøå ÆØÅ & íjj´¨¨¨¨fdfd""', '3000', '25', 'kjole.xml', '', '', '');
INSERT INTO options_to_products VALUES ('', @variant_id, '1', '');
INSERT INTO options_to_products VALUES ('', @variant_id, '', '4');
```

Comment: isn't it dangerous to import code from strangers …?

Comment: This code is not from strangers. It is code my system generates. Reason why I do it this way is irrelevant for the question :)

Comment: With very big files, I would tend to try and split the files myself. I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883079/best-practice-import-mysql-file-in-php-split-queries) a while back and got pretty good results.

Comment: Does it have to produce a "sql batch" file then? Couldn't it store the queries in a format that is easier to parse/separate again? E.g. via var_export()? Or -if the file can potentially become big- in a format that allows you to read the statements one by one (or in chunks)?

Comment: @VolkerK: Interesting... Will look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the file into a string and then pass it to [mysqli::multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Standard disclaimers regarding untrusted sources for data/queries/executable-code et cetera apply.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it to [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query)