# how to split sql queries and execute them using java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a files containing sql scripts both DDL and DML scripts like create, insert, update, delete, create views etc.

i need to split them correctly an execute them, any suggestions..

thanks in advance

Comment: That is quite a vague question...

Comment: what format will the file containing the SQL scripts have? i.e. will you have one SQL statement per line, or could SQL statements be spread over multiple lines? Or are comments allowed in the SQL script file?

Comment: sql statements in multiple line eg. formatted sql queries with more than 30 lines like views, and the file will also contains the commented lines

Answer (score -1):

eventually duplicated question: [Split multiple SQL statements into individual SQL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633014/split-multiple-sql-statements-into-individual-sql-statements)

To execute you could use something like:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
for(String statement : statements) {
    stmt.addBatch(statement);
}
stmt.executeBatch();
```